# Character encoding problem

Tags: c, encoding, character-encoding

I was recently editing a Unicode-encoded text file that also includes Thai characters (alongside "normal" characters). For some reason, after each sequence of Thai characters, a new line appeared.

After some mucking around with C, trying to remove all newline characters, I fired up vim to inspect the file. Apparently, after each Thai character sequence, there appears a "^M" string (without quotes).

Why is this happening, and what's that "^M"? I've found that I can fix the problem by removing the last three characters from the Thai string, but there surely must be a more elegant way to fix this ...

Comment: Most likely its a file encoding issue.  Unix and Windows have different conventions for newline.  Does your C code use `\r`? Does it open files in text mode or binary mode?

Comment: My C code uses \n. The original file was UTF-8 encoded. No newline characters are problematic, only foreign characters create the issue (chinese characters, too, as I just realised)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the fact that you have some Thai characters in the file. The `^M` ('carrot M') is the representation of a Microsoft (DOS) carriage return. [Dos2unix](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html) the file to get rid of these before editing it in vim.